# Reference for isomorphism between group cohomology and singular cohomology

Tags: reference-request, cohomology, group-cohomology, sheaf-cohomology, classifying-spaces

Let $G$ be a (discrete) group, $X$ a topological space that works as a classifying space for $G$, and $\mathcal{L}$ a local system on $X$ with stalk $L$. It is a fairly standard result that

$$ H^i(G, L) \cong H^i(X,\mathcal{L})$$

where the left hand side is the group cohomology and the right hand side is sheaf cohomology. This follows from the equivalence of categories of local systems on (nice enough) $X$ and representations of the fundamental group $G$, but I can't seem to find a paper or a book where this isomorphism of cohomologies is explicitly proven/stated, and I would like to be able to provide a reference. Any suggestions?

On a similar note, is there any sense in which this isomorphism holds for $X$ an orbifold with orbifold fundamental group $G$?

Comment: What definition are you using for $H^i(G,L)$?

Comment: The shortest definition would be the derived functors of the functor taking a representation to its invariants, though it can also be defined in terms of a cochain complex

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For *CW-complexes*, this is roughly spelled out in *Ken Brown's bible*: Proposition II.4.1 (which is the combination of Proposition I.4.2 and Proposition II.2.4), assuming the algebraic-definition of group cohomology in Section II.3 (effectively we have explicit maps between their explicit $\mathbb{Z}G$-free resolutions of $\mathbb{Z}$ which you can then twist with local coefficients as clarified in Chapter III.1). For *general spaces*, this is Exercise II.4.2, which he gives hints and furthermore gives the foundational reference that writes it out (Eilenberg--Maclane's 1945 *"Relations between homology and homotopy
groups of spaces"*).

More generally, for any path-connected topological space X we can construct a discrete group G and K(G,1) inducing (co)homology isomorphisms (reference [Kan–Thurston theorem](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0040938376900409?via%3Dihub)) and then apply the above.

Comment: What exactly is the relevance of the Kan–Thurston theorem here?  The OP explicitly states that X is a classifying space for a discrete group G, which by definition makes it weakly equivalent (and not merely homology equivalent) to K(G,1).

Comment: What does the Kan-Thurston theorem have to do with this?  We already know that $X$ is a $K(G,1)$.

Comment: You're right, updated response.